# Does hinsehen/hinschauen take auf or zu?

Tags: preposition, verb-usage

Attempting to translate a line from Asimov's, I Robot:

> His photoelectric eyes focused reproachfully upon the Earthman.

I said,

> Seine fotoelektrische Augen **schauten** vorwurfsvoll **auf** den Erdenmensch **hin**.

But I was corrected with:

> Seine fotoelektrische Augen schauten vorwurfsvoll **zum** Erdenmensch hin.

When I look at sehen in DWDS, because the hinsehen entry is silent about prepositions, I find, however,

> c) den Blick auf ein bestimmtes Ziel richten, **auf etw. hinsehen**.

While Duden has for hinsehen:

> **nach/zu** jemandem hinsehen

I am confused. Which preposition(s) does hinsehen take? (And I assume it is the same for hinschauen?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hinsehen* and *hinschauen* do not take obligatory objects.  You can use them correctly without any preposition phrase at all:

> Er sah genauer hin.

However, they are are of course frequently combined with a "freie Angabe" containing the target of looking.  This can be pretty arbitrary -- the preposition depends on the geometry of the action (i.e., the usual rules how to use prepositions according to surface, containment, etc.), and sometimes style.  You are theoretically free to choose, but there are only so many prepositions logically fitting, of which *auf* and *zu* are the most common one.

> Sie sah auf/unter den Tisch hin.

> Sie sah zur Tür hin.

> Sie sah vor/hinter/neben das Haus hin.

> Sie sah zwischen die Bäume hin.

> Sie sah in den Kühlschrank hin.

> Sie sah nach den Bergen hin.

(The last one sounds really old-fashioned though.  More like 19th century literature.)

But note that almost always, you can just drop the *hin*, and the sentence will sound less stilted.  Think of it more as an extra adverbial specifying that the action has a "towards" directionality.

---

In your specific case, I guess you'd rather tend towards a more literary style, so the *hin* is appropriate.  And *auf* is more specific than *zu* (which could also be only "somewhere in his general direction").  So I'd write

> Seine fotoelektrische**n** Augen schauten vorwurfsvoll auf den Erdenmensch**en** hin.

(*Den Mensch* is acceptable as well, but *den Menschen* is more literary, again.)

Comment: I really appreciate the insights provided into the nuances of the language given here. It is exactly this kind of depth that is available to one learning German nowhere else, and it makes learning the language so much more fun and enlightening.

Comment: It is also a pleasure to answer high quality questions and sharpen one's metalinguistic competence.

Answer (score 1):

DWDS has this quote:

> Mit einem guten, mitleidigen Lächeln sah er zu ihr hin. [Duncker, Dora: Jugend. In: Deutsche Literatur von Frauen, Berlin: Directmedia Publ. 2001 [1905], S. 9455]

Actually none of these prepositions is used frequently, since either another prefix for *sehen* is more streamlined:

> Sie sah ihn *an*. (instead of "Sie sah zu ihm hin").

or there is no target involved right from the start:

> Er konnte gar nicht hinsehen.